# ActionListener and ActionEvent not working - trying to click JButtons

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton

I am really new to Java, so this is probably an easy fix, but I'm trying to make a button clear the screen when it is pressed for a civil-war based game for a school project This is my code that s causing the problem:

OpeningScreen.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

//import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JButton;

//import civil_war_platfomer.levels.Levels;


public class OpeningScreen {
    public JFrame _frame;
    protected static JButton _startButton;
    protected static JButton _levelSelector;
    protected static JButton _optionsButton;
    protected static int _sizeX;
    protected static int _sizeY;

    public OpeningScreen() {
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start Game");
        JButton levelSelector = new JButton("Select Level");
        JButton optionsMenu = new JButton("Options");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("War Games");
        startButton.setBounds(100, 200, 300, 50);
        levelSelector.setBounds(100, 300, 300, 50);
        optionsMenu.setBounds(100, 400, 300, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(startButton);
        frame.getContentPane().add(levelSelector);
        frame.getContentPane().add(optionsMenu);
        _frame = frame;
    }

    public void initWindow(JFrame frame, int sizeX, int sizeY) {
        frame.setSize(sizeX, sizeY);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        _sizeX = sizeX;
        _sizeY = sizeY;
    }

private void clearScreen(){
        frame.dispose();
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(_sizeX, _sizeY);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void passControl(Levels level) {

    }
}

private class ClickEvent implements ActionListener {
        public boolean startIsClicked = false;
        public boolean selectIsClicked = false;
        public boolean optionsIsClicked = false;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
            if (a.getActionCommand().equals("startButton")) {
                startIsClicked = true;
            }
            if (a.getActionCommand().equals("levelSelector")) {
                selectIsClicked = true;
            }
            if (a.getActionCommand().equals("optionsMenu")) {
                optionsIsClicked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The player class is another class that I've made that defines mechanics and such. Like I said, I am really new to Java so I don't know what is going on and its probably a simple fix.

This is Main.java:

```
import civil_war_platfomer.OpeningScreen;


public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    OpeningScreen screen = new OpeningScreen();
    screen.initWindow(screen._frame, 500, 500);
  }
}
```

Like I said earlier, I'm kind of an extreme newbie with Java so its probably an actually dumb small problem.

Thanks!!

Comment: [Avoid null layouts in Swing](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/114-avoid-null-layouts-in-swing) and 
[Watch your naming](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) Also [don't use `static`](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/108-static-is-a-swear-word) 'Clearing the screen' might suggest a `CardLayout` though difficult to know what you mean by that

Comment: Yeah I don't know what you mean by "clearing the screen" either, can you point out what code you are referring to?  What does it do now and what do want to do, specifically, instead?

Comment: Please consider posting enough code that we can run the code you posted and see the problem.  It's called a [mcve].

Comment: @g00se: By clearing the screen I mean a total wipe of `JFrame`. Nothing should be shown

Comment: @markspace Right now, for testing, I have omitted clearing the screen to see if `ActionEvent` even works

Comment: Well, that doesn't help us find the problem, does it?  Please add details to allow us to debug the problem.

Comment: Update: I think its the compilers fault because I made an AI write a program that would clear the screen and it doesn't